# conditional where on the basis of value of another model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have three models

**Invoice**

**Studio**

**R_studio_pay**

Relationships are as follows

studio **hasMany** Invoice

studio **hasOne** R_studio_pay

I need to get invoices->where('recurring', 'single')->get() if a column is_r is 1 in R_studio_pay else i don't want the where clause.

I tried using whereHas studio-> wherehas R_studio_pay but conditional where cannot be done.

```
$invoices = invoice::with('studio')->whereHas('studio', function($query) {
   $query->whereHas('r_studio_pay', function($query) {
       $query->where('is_r', 1);
   });
})->where('recurring', 'single')
```

But couldn't apply conditional where.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. However, you should add a return statement in your callbacks. `return $query->where('is_r', 1);` instead of `$query->where('is_r', 1);`. Try the code below.

```
$invoices = invoice::with('studio')->whereHas('studio', function($query){
   return $query->whereHas('r_studio_pay', function($query){
       return $query->where('is_r', 1);
   });
})->where('recurring', 'single');
```

Comment: If is_r = null then i want all invoice. The where clause needs to be conditional on is_r.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55345529/return-keyword-in-query-callback/55345669?noredirect=1#comment97416867_55345669