# Return keyword in query callback

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Is it necessary to write return keyword while using whereHas in laravel.

For eg. return $query->where('status', 1);

```
$posts = App\Post::whereHas('comments', function ($query) {
    $query->whereHas('content', function ($query){
       $query->where('status', 1);
    });
})->get();
```

Do we need to write return in every query callback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you're modifying the query builder instance passed to your closure by calling `$query->where('status', 1);`.  Since objects are passed by reference and `where()` mutates this instance, there's no need to return anything.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55338139/conditional-where-on-the-basis-of-value-of-another-model/55338206#55338206

Comment: Yeah, there's no need  to return there so that answer wouldn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need. Also you can use whereHas with nested relationship.
Example:

```
$posts = App\Post::whereHas('comments.content', function ($query) {
    $query->where('status', 1);
})->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

No. Because you have the same object (and modify it) inside every function. No need to return.